# Setting email body background color in a VBA created HTML Outlook email

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I have an Excel macro that creates and sends emails. I want to set the background colour to match an inserted image. It is a dark blue shade so I will also look at changing the text to white.

Most searches show results for table background not the entire email body background. Is it possible to change the background of an Outlook email in VBA using HTML Body?

```
xHTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
             & "<Body style = bgcolor=”#1b1c37”>" _
             & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=3>" 
_
             & "<p>Dear " + Worksheets("SHeet2").Range("T3") + ",</p></p> 
</p>" _
             & "<p>The weekly results .</p></p>" _
             & "<br>" _
             & "<IMG align=baseline border=0 hspace=0 src=cid:myident>" + 
",</p></p></p>" _
             & "<br>If you have any questions feel free to give me a call  
</font></Body></span>"
```

The code produces an email but "BGcolor" isn't changing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
 "<Body style="bgcolor=#1b1c37">"
```

or

```
 "<Body style="backgroundcolor=#1b1c37">"
```

Make sure that you create a well-formed HTML markup. I'd recommend testing your sample HTML markup in Word because Outlook uses it for rendering message bodies.